# How to read the header of xml

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, stax

i have xml file, and i want to read the header of it whic is as follows using StAX:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
```

in the switch-case statement i ahve the following cases but non of them detects the header

```
switch (event) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
        case XMLStreamConstants.ATTRIBUTE:
        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
        }
```

please let me jnow how to detect the header using StAx.

Answer (score 3):

There is no event for the XML declaration ("header") specifically, but the `XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT` event is associated with `XMLStreamReader` methods for getting at the information:

- `getVersion()`
- `isStandalone()`
- `standaloneSet()`
- `getCharacterEncodingScheme()`

For example:

```
case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
    System.out.print("version=" + xmlstreamreader.getVersion());
    break;
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html.